# Audio front panel noise?

Tags: audio

I want to use the front-panel audio connections for my headphones, but when I use it, it makes a static noise like my HDD.

There is no problem with the wires. This sound starts only when Windows starts.

If I am in BIOS, and my HDD is on, when Windows is loading, there is no sound.

I have Windows 7 and I deactivated the Beep from my device manager already.

I have an integrated 5.1 Realtek audio card. My motherboard is *Gigabyte GA-H55M-UD2H*.

Thank you very much!

Comment: ...and the audio from the rear-panel connector is perfectly OK? (I have the same problem.) Unfortunately, it appears to be surprisingly common for front-panel audio ports to exhibit this kind of _static_ when coupled with front panel USB ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the motherboard is to blame.

If your front panel has a USB I/O try to disconnect the USB cable from the motherboard to the front panel. If the static noise is gone try modifying the circuitboard so the ground connectors are no longer connected to the headphone ground pin ([HDD use + front panel audio = static noise - Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/267466-13-front-panel-audio-static-noise#t2476513)) (the front panel shares the same ground for USB and audio I/O).

Answer (score 1):

My laptop's audio output also has some background noise, only apparent when playing into a big amp or using earbuds.  The fact is, most audio circuits in PCs are practically afterthoughts, not designed to isolate properly from the system's electrical noise, especially integrated chipsets.

Most likely, when you hear no noise, it's before the audio driver has been loaded, and so there's no output at all.

If you want better sound without noise, invest in a good sound card, maybe a Turtle Beach one, or even a good (not a cheap) external USB sound card.